# Can virus hide into installer files?

Tags: virus, anti-virus

You get a zip file from somewhere, download it (several files) and you get the executable ones and send them to VirusTotal.com for example.

They appear clean.

Could it happen that the installer is clean but install viruses on the computer after being run from the other unscanned files (as they are not executables?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They appear clean.

That just means there is no virus included in it which is already included in virustotal's database.

> Could it happen that the installer is clean but install viruses on the
> computer after being run from the other unscanned files (as they are
> not executables?)

Yes, it can happen. Other files can also contain virus.

I also feel some confusion in your question, not only .exe files contain executable code, dll-s are also executed and actually there are a big number of file types can be executed. It could be hard to know all of them and upload for virus check.

Comment: So it is quite easy for a virus to be spread into multiple files in a way no antivirus can detect them until the installer is executed and the files are assembled and potentially already executed by the installer. This leads to a situation were you are only safe if you get realtime protection as no static file analysis can save you from this right?

Comment: You're never _safe_. If you have suspicions, you should not be running downloaded executables.